# UIPageViewController in ios 5.1

Tags: iphone, ios5.1, uipageviewcontroller

I am using `UIPageViewController` to display two view controllers.i want this view controllers to be displayed in different pages and `on swiping`, page should get turned. When i run this in iPad simulator 6.0 it works fine but when i run it in iPad simulator 5.1 then both the view controllers are displayed on the same page. Here is the code

```
NSDictionary *options =  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid] forKey:UIPageViewControllerOptionSpineLocationKey];

self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl
                                                              navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:options];

    //Step 2:
    //Assign the delegate and datasource as self.
    self.pageViewController.delegate = self;
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

    //Step 3:
    //Set the initial view controllers.
    GameSelectViewController *gameViewController = [[GameSelectViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GameSelectViewController" bundle:nil];

    HighscoreViewController *highScoreViewController = [[HighscoreViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HighscoreViewController" bundle:nil];

    viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:highScoreViewController,gameViewController, nil];

    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    //Step 4:
    //ViewController containment steps
    //Add the pageViewController as the childViewController
    [self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];

    //Add the view of the pageViewController to the current view
    [self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];

    //Call didMoveToParentViewController: of the childViewController, the UIPageViewController instance in our case.
    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    //Step 5:
    // set the pageViewController's frame as an inset rect.
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = self.view.frame;
```

I am new in iPhone development. Please do the needful. Thanks.